# Simpler way to solve this in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations:

$|z|^2=|z-e^{i\theta}-e^{i2\theta}|^2$,

$\frac{d}{d\theta}\big(|z-e^{i\theta}-e^{i2\theta}|^2\big)=0$,

that I want to solve for $z$. $\theta$ is real, and $z$ is independent of $\theta$. I can find the solution $z=\frac{1}{3}\big(2e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}\big)$ by assuming a solution of the form $z=ae^{i\theta}+be^{i2\theta}$, and inserting this in the two equations give me $a$ and $b$.

I am wondering is there is a simpler method to arrive to the solution, without having to assume a solution.

Comment: Is $z$ independent from $\theta$? And does the first relation holds for every $\theta$?

Comment: Yes to both, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Then, isn't the second equation redundant?

Comment: I think the first one only is not enough to determine both $a$ and $b$